# Dynamic loading of controller + factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am developing angularjs application that should be possible to extend with "addins". In the simplified case addin is just a pair of js+html files. Each addin should have one or more controllers and one or more factories.
Below is an example of adding with one controller and one factory:

JS:

```
angular.module('addins.basic', [])

angular.module('addins.basic').factory('BasicAddinFactory', [BasicAddinFactory]);

function BasicAddinFactory()
{
    var fact =
    {
        Invoke: function ()
        {
            console.log('BasicAddinFactory.Invoke');
        },
        GetClients: function ()
        {
            return ["aa", "bb"];
        }
    }

    return fact;
}

angular.module('addins.basic').controller('BasicAddinController', ['$scope', 'BasicAddinFactory', BasicAddinController]);

function BasicAddinController($scope, $injector, addin)
{
    //var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'addins.basic'])
    //var addin = injector.get('BasicAddinFactory');

    $scope.expr = 'BasicAddinFactory: ' + addin.GetClients()[0];
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="BasicAddinController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="expr">
    <span>{{ expr }}</span>
</div>
```

Loading addins dynamically is not an issue using techniques widely described on the internet: by adding JS script and HTML to the DOM. Everything loads fine until I try to inject dependency on BasicAddinFactory to BasicAddinController. After doing so I got error during dynamic loading: Unknown provider: addinProvider <- addin.

The interesting part is that if I do not explicitly inject dependency everything loads fine and I even can access factory instance from controller (or from the parent code that loads the "addin") by using commented code in the sample above. But that is quite ugly and I do not really want to have it like so.

I would appreciate if anyone could point me out where my mistake is.

Thanks.

UPDATE: [Sample plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vys1yhNQYA8ejZMSXSS9?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with how Angular actually handles dependencies behind the scenes. The [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) process handles registering all of your various services.

When you dynamically add modules you will need to register those new modules yourself. One way to do is having a globally available register function for each type of service like so:

```
app.config(['$controllerProvider',
  '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide',
  function($controllerProvider,
    $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {

    app.register = {
      controller: $controllerProvider.register,
      directive: $compileProvider.directive,
      filter: $filterProvider.register,
      factory: $provide.factory,
      service: $provide.service
    };
  }
]);
```

You then change your dynamic modules to register their services like so:

```
app.register.factory('BasicAddinFactory', [BasicAddinFactory]);
```

[A Plunker example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/jeqx6rdKFIVsuYZz2aQ3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this is not so. Adding services that are not used in controller does not change anything. If they are injected correctly - they do not break the "compiling" of it.

Comment: It's not that they're not used, it's that the order of the dependency array matters. An example: http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/022mnqzp/3/

Comment: I am sorry. That was just a typo when I was preparing code for stackowerflow. Here is a plunk that illustrates the problem: [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/vys1yhNQYA8ejZMSXSS9?p=preview). Try remove there injection to factory and it works fine.

Comment: @Amid Ahh okay I misunderstood the problem. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Felix. With your changes its working fine. But now both addin factory and controller are loaded into the main 'app' module. And line: angular.module('addins.basic', []) is basically useless. Is it possible to keep "addin" code loaded in the addin module and still be able to call its functions from outside?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, unfortunately modules can only be registered on startup and loading modules dynamically gets [pretty complicated pretty fast](http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/). If you need the lazy loading functionality I would suggest using [this already available library](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).